# Highlighting of submenu with li<a> with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am coding a dropdown submenu as below:

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li class="enter-top-level">
        <a href="#entering">
            Enter Data
            <ul id="enter_scheme_global">
                <li class='submenu'>
                    <a href="#enter_scheme">
                        Scheme Details
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class='submenu'>
                    <a href="#enter_transformer">
                        Transformer
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class='submenu'>
                    <a href="#enter_AIS">
                        AIS
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class='submenu'>
                    <a href="#enter_GIS">
                        GIS
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I want to give it a animated slideDown and slideUp effect with jquery and I tried the following :

```
$('a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(500);
    $(this).parent('.submenu').css({"background-color" : "#700000"});
});//end $('a').hover function*/

$('a').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').fadeToggle(500);
    $(this).parent('.submenu').css({"background-color" : "#C8C8C8"});
});//end $('a').hover function*/
```

but without success. Any help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with the code.

First, your HTML needs to be changed. Your top level `a` tag wraps all the elements, which would render the children `a` elements useless. You also don't need to have two separate functions for the `mouseover/mouseout`. You can use the `hover()` method. Also, targeting the parent `li` will allow the menu to stay open as the mouse is still over it (as opposed the `a` element). Here is the working code:

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xf02743m/1/

HTML

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li class="enter-top-level"><a href="#entering">Enter Data</a>

        <ul id="enter_scheme_global">
            <li class='submenu'><a href="#enter_scheme">Scheme Details</a>

            </li>
            <li class='submenu'><a href="#enter_transformer">Transformer</a>

            </li>
            <li class='submenu'><a href="#enter_AIS">AIS</a>

            </li>
            <li class='submenu'><a href="#enter_GIS">GIS</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS - hide the submenu first

```
#enter_scheme_global {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".enter-top-level").hover(function () {
    $(".enter-top-level ul").slideDown("slow");
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color" : "#700000"})
}, function(){
    $(".enter-top-level ul").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color" : "#C8C8C8"});
});
```

Comment: @SukalyanGhoshal - If this has solved your problem then please mark this post as the answer.

Comment: @SukalyanGhoshal as Lee Taylor said, if this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. This will help future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("a").hover(
  function() {
     $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500); // 'next' finds the next occurring element to the current 'a' tag
     $(this).next('ul').find('.submenu').css({"background-color" : "#700000"});
  }, function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500);
    $(this).next('ul').find('.submenu').css({"background-color" : "#C8C8C8"});
  }
);
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/9882acxn/4/